# Torch does not find GPU on pytorch-training:1.10.0-gpu-py38 container

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

Torch does not find Cuda on GPU instance and official SageMaker training container

```
763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.10.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker
```

The same outcome is seen when running container on SageMaker Notebook instance `ml.p3.2xlarge` (docker pull from console) and EC2 instance `p3.2xlarge`.

*Current behavior:*

```
sudo docker pull 763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.10.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash 709fa9395949
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available()) -> False"
```

*Expected behavior:*

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())" -> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the GPUs in docker run. For example:

```
docker run --gpus all  -it --entrypoint /bin/bash 709fa9395949
```